# sql from xquery need some explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, xquery

I came across this line of code and it's not making any sense to me

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DateT)
        FROM cico
        GROUP BY DateT
        ORDER BY DateT
        FOR XML PATH('')
            ,TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

I know `for xml path('')` is to create xml structure of result set returned from select statement

but what is  `(select ....,TYPE)`.value(....)

the above line is simply assigning `TYPE` to `(select..., )` only brackets. its not a function. in other words its like this   `select .... ,TYPE`

another thing that is difficult for me to understand is why we are assigning value to bracket `(...).value(...)`

Comment: @TT. i know i already read it. but my question is how this query is correct (select....  , type).value(..). why assigning value to select statement what using  `,type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From [Basic Syntax of the FOR XML Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx)

> **TYPE**
>      Specifies that the query returns the results as the **xml** type.

---

- From [TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx)

> SQL Server support for the xml (Transact-SQL) enables you to optionally request that the result of a FOR XML query be returned as **xml data type** by specifying the **TYPE** directive. This allows you to process the result of a FOR XML query on the server.

`SELECT ... FRO XML PATH(''), TYPE` will returns `xml`, then you can use xquery methods like `.value()` over it.
Note that without using `TYPE` your query will returns an error :

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

Because you can not use xquery methods over a `nvarchar(max)` result.

Comment: can u add details to arguments of stuff? why we are passing  `1,1,''`?

Comment: `STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )` => And in your query will remove first '`,`'  ;).